# Limiting List Views by Role

Tags: list-view

Our Salesforce org has the following role hierarchy:

[image]

The lead list view is shared to the following roles:

[image]

For some reason Phone Advisor can see list views that should only be shared with RA Leader and and RA Advisor and internal subordinates. I also tried to restrict by individual role, instead of using RA Advisor and subordinate, but this did not work.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the role hierarchy works. Given Alice in role A, Bob in role B, and Charlie in role C, where both B and C report to A, gives the following sharing profiles:

- Role A includes Alice
- Role B includes Alice and Bob
- Role C includes Alice and Charlie
- Roles and Subordinates A includes Alice, Bob, and Charlie
- Roles and Subordinates B includes Alice and Bob
- Roles and Subordinates C includes Alice and Charlie

In the default model, these are the only profiles available. You can't share explicitly with Charlie without Alice also having access. Even a manual share with Charlie creates a sharing profile that includes both Charlie and Alice; managers have the same access as their subordinates in the hierarchy, and managers can always perform any action their subordinate could. For example, if Charlie owns a lead, Alice can delete that lead or transfer that lead to another user (assuming her profile allowed her to do so).

Some objects can have this feature disabled through Setup > Security Controls > Sharing Settings, but this will affect sharing rules and manual sharing globally for that object. Standard objects apparently can't be configured to ignore the hierarchy. I would advise you to read the Help & Training topic on the sharing model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess that means I'll just have to live with them seeing that view. No worries! Thanks again!!